# Point-free style with objects/records in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, function, methods

I'm getting stymied by the way "dot notation" works with objects and records when trying to program in a point-free functional style (which I think is a great, concise way to use a functional language that curries by default).

Is there an operator or function I'm missing that lets me do something like:
`(.) object method` instead of `object.method`?

(From what I was reading about the new `?` operator, I think it works like this. Except it requires definition and gets into the whole dynamic binding thing, which I don't think I need.)

In other words, can I apply a method to its object as an argument like I would apply a normal function to its argument?

Comment: As disturbing as it sounds and looks (due to the need to parenthesize more) I'm afraid there's no way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: you can of course create let-bound functions in a module that call a method on a given type...  For example in the code

```
let l = [1;2;3]
let h1 = l.Head 
let h2 = List.hd l
```

there is a sense in which "List.hd" is the version of what you want for ".Head on a list".  Or locally, you can always do e.g.

```
let AnotherWay = (fun (l:list<_>) -> l.Head)
let h3 = AnotherWay l
```

But there is nothing general, since there is no good way to 'name' an arbitrary instance method on a given type; 'AnotherWay' shows a way to "make a function out of the 'Head' property on a 'list<_>' object", but you need such boilerplate for every instance method you want to treat as a first-class function value.

I have suggested creating a language construct to generalize this:

> With regards to language design
>   suggestions, what if
>
> ```
>  SomeType..Foo optArgs   // note *two* dots
> ```
>
> meant
>
> ```
>  fun (x : SomeType) -> x.Foo optArgs
> ```
>
> ?

In which case you could write

```
list<_>..Head
```

as a way to 'functionize' this instance property, but if we ever do anything in that arena in F#, it would be post-VS2010.

Comment: There have been cases where I needed to 'map' a sequence of strings into their respective lengths, and had to create a lambda just so I could access its instance properties.  I would love to see a way to access them statically like this.  It would make some existing functions redundant though. (Like List.hd)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is: no you can't. Dot (.) is not an operator in F#, it is built into the language, so can't be used as function.